# Why does wp_enqueue_script ignore my 'wp_head' hook?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I would like `css_head_scripts` and `js_head_scripts` to be appended to `wp-head`

but Wordpress completely ignores it? Am I missing something?

```
    function css_head_scripts() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'Master Stylesheet', get_template_directory_uri()."style.css" );
    }
    function js_head_scripts() {
        echo '<!--[if lt IE 9]>';
        wp_enqueue_script( "HTML5 Shiv", "https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js" );
        wp_enqueue_script( "Respond.js", "https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js" );
        echo '<![endif]-->';
    }
    function js_footer_scripts() {
        wp_enqueue_script( "My jQuery", "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" );
        wp_enqueue_script( "Bootstrap", get_template_directory_uri()."/js/bootstrap.min.js" );
    }
    add_action('wp_head', 'css_head_scripts');
    add_action('wp_head', 'js_head_scripts');
    add_action('wp_footer', 'js_footer_scripts');
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a number of issues with the code you've posted.

### 1) These shouldn't be hooked to wp_head or wp_footer.

The correct hook is wp_enqueue_scripts.

Change:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'css_head_scripts');
add_action('wp_head', 'js_head_scripts');
add_action('wp_footer', 'js_footer_scripts');
```

To:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'css_head_scripts');
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'js_head_scripts');
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'js_footer_scripts');
```

### 2) Your handles should be lowercase and shouldn't contain spaces.

For example change:

```
function css_head_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'Master Stylesheet', get_template_directory_uri()."style.css" );
}
```

To:

```
function css_head_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'master-stylesheet', get_template_directory_uri()."style.css" );
}
```

### 3) A different function can be used for the main stylesheet.

```
function css_head_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'master-stylesheet', get_stylesheet_uri() );
}
```

### 4) You shouldn't be enqueuing a custom version of jQuery.

Remove `wp_enqueue_script( "My jQuery", "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" );`

### 5) The correct way to load a script in the footer

Change:

```
function js_footer_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( "bootstrap", get_template_directory_uri() . "/js/bootstrap.min.js" );
}
```

To:

```
function js_footer_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( "bootstrap", get_template_directory_uri() . "/js/bootstrap.min.js", array( 'jquery' ), false, true );
}
```

### 6) The correct way to add IE conditionals.

```
function js_head_scripts() {
    global $wp_scripts;    

    wp_register_script( "html5-shiv", "https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js", array(), '3.7.0' );
    $wp_scripts->add_data( 'html5-shiv', 'conditional', 'lt IE 9' );

    wp_enqueue_script( "respond.js", "https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js", array(), '1.4.2' );
    $wp_scripts->add_data( 'respond.js', 'conditional', 'lt IE 9' );
}
```

### 7) Do you need 3 functions for this?

Combine all of this into a single function

If you've been following along so far your completed code should look something like this:

```
function wpse_scripts_styles() {
    global $wp_scripts;

    wp_enqueue_style( 'master-stylesheet', get_stylesheet_uri() );

    wp_enqueue_script( "bootstrap", get_template_directory_uri() . "/js/bootstrap.min.js", array( 'jquery' ), false, true );

    wp_register_script( "html5-shiv", "https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js", array(), '3.7.0' );
    $wp_scripts->add_data( 'html5-shiv', 'conditional', 'lt IE 9' );

    wp_register_script( "respond.js", "https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js", array(), '1.4.2' );
    $wp_scripts->add_data( 'respond.js', 'conditional', 'lt IE 9' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_scripts_styles' );
```

Further reading: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

### UPDATE:

Disappointingly the IE conditional doesn't work.
https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16024

A work around for this would be to load them in the head with the wp_head action but this isn't ideal. Following on from the example above the method you'd use is:

```
function wpse_ie_conditional_scripts() { ?>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <?php
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpse_ie_conditional_scripts' );
```

Comment: Thanks a million. This taught me a lot. Two things: I need jquery in the footer. How would I does that work? Would I just add another `wp_enqueue_style` and put `true` as the argument for `in_footer`? Lastly, what is `$wp_scripts`?

Comment: The add_data method where you see 'conditional' and 'lt IE 9' add the IE conditionals. When you're adding JS you would use `wp_enqueue_script` rather than `wp_enqueue_style`. WordPress already has jQuery enqueued in the code above. You would have to dequeue it then enqueue it again with in_footer set to true.

Comment: Is there a reason why you used `wp_register_script` instead of `wp_enqueue_script` for `html5-shiv`?

Also, `html5-shiv` and `respond.js` aren't being commented out w/the IE conditionals once it renders in HTML?

Comment: Great Great answer. especially part 4. where did people learned to do that ??? and why ?

Comment: @ObmerkKronen I have no idea but it's a step up from including jQuery directly in the header :)

Comment: @Wilhelm Both respond.js and html5-shiv were supposed to be using register instead of enqueue in the code I posted. I have since updated it. The scripts need to be registered for the add_data method to work.

Comment: `$wp_scripts->add_data` only works on stylesheets. I used another method for displaying the conditional js. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a fix for anyone else who finds this.